# Django static files dont find

Tags: django, python-3.x, bootstrap-4, django-templates

i wrote this and my static files don't load
my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

error

```
[08/Mar/2020 16:51:18] "GET /static/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1808
```

my Directories

```
    ├───.idea
│   ├───codeStyles
│   ├───dataSources
│   │   └───d4ce3b9a-7046-4b9c-88b6-dab8cf342341
│   │       └───storage_v2
│   │           └───_src_
│   │               └───database
│   │                   └───iotkaran.u-MyVw
│   │                       └───schema
│   └───inspectionProfiles
├───accounts
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───accounts
│   └───__pycache__
├───iotkaran
│   └───__pycache__
├───static
│   ├───admin
│   │   ├───css
│   │   │   └───vendor
│   │   │       └───select2
│   │   ├───fonts
│   │   ├───img
│   │   │   └───gis
│   │   └───js
│   │       ├───admin
│   │       └───vendor
│   │           ├───jquery
│   │           ├───select2
│   │           │   └───i18n
│   │           └───xregexp
│   ├───bootstrap
│   ├───bootstrap-4.4.1-dist
│   │   ├───css
│   │   └───js
│   └───img
├───templates
└───venv
    ├───Include
    ├───Lib
    │   └───site-packages
    └───Scripts
```

and my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa-IR">
{% load static %}

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'img/favicon.png' %}">
</head>
```

i changed folder placement from user/[user] to myDocument\myprojects. also i added everyone as owner of folder. but still not working.
thank you in advance

Comment: do you used {%load staticfiles%} or not, please could you set more details about your html files you will use?

Comment: Please show your folder structure and tell whether DEBUG=true or false.

Comment: @IvanStarostin yes debug is true

Comment: @abdelhamedabdin i use {% load static %}

Comment: @IvanStarostin i don't have access to my pc now but i will send that as soon as possible

Comment: get me more files like html or py file about your errors bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Fixed that
i just deleted >> 'django.contrib.staticfiles', << 
in settings.py in installed apps and it fixed

[Delete this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLoSg.png)

Answer (score 0):

For local development usually I use `STATICFILES_DIRS` like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

You can add all directories where you save your static files in `STATICFILES_DIRS` separate by comas, 
but when you want to deploy your project you need to set `STATIC_ROOT` then run `python manage.py collecstatic` and finally serve your static files on your server. For more detail you can read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/).

Comment: I used my code before and it worked. But now i don't know why that's not working. I started my server as admin too but it still doesn't work.